# git cat-file tag TAG return: "fatal: git cat-file TAG: bad file"

Tags: git

I have the following tree:

```
O---O---O---O <- master
 \--O---O <- work branch
        /\
        ||
        TAG
```

When I run git cat-file I get an error:

```
> git cat-file tag TAG
fatal: git cat-file TAG: bad file
```

Do anyone has an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that `TAG` points to a true tag object and isn't just a lightweight tag? Try `git cat-file -t TAG` to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect to happen?  Perhaps you want:

```
git cat-file commit TAG
```

... which prints some information about the commit that `TAG` points to.  (i.e. the `<type>` that `git cat-file` is expecting should be `commit` rather than `tag`.)

*Update:* as I mentioned in a comment below, if what you want is the object name (the hash) of the commit, you can get that with:

```
git rev-parse --verify TAG
```

Comment: I want to get <object> of the TAG

Comment: If you just want the object name, you can do `git rev-parse --verify TAG`.  Is that what you want?